# Detecting #<unspecified> in Scheme list

Tags: scheme, guile

I have a function which return a list of values. Some of these values may be empty lists themselves, while some are not. However, at the end of every list, there is a `#<unspecified>` value present. I understand that this value is returned when the function does not return anything.

I want to trim this value, along with other null lists.

My list is like this:
`(() () MD- MC+. #<unspecified>)`

I intend to apply a filter function to this list.
The criteria that I will be applying is `null?`.
However, when this is applied to the `#<unspecified>` value, it gives me false. How can I remove the `#<unspecified>` value from the list?

The output of this list after applying the filter function should be:
`(MD- MC+)`

How do I do this?

Comment: Is the dot really a part of the symbol or perhaps the list looks like `(() () MD- MC+ . #<unspecified>)` ?

Comment: It is not part of the symbol. It is as you said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list is not a proper list but a dotted list. All higher order functions like `filter`, `fold`, `map`, ... require the lists to be proper so such list cannot be used.

I'm wondering if perhaps the reason you are stuck with such list is because of a bug in the procedure that produced the list. Usually if you have a recursive procedure..

```
(define (list-add1 lst)
  (if (pair? lst) 
      (cons (add1 (car lst)) (list-add1 (cdr lst)))))
```

Now, every schemer sees right away that this is the same as:

```
(define (list-add1 lst)
  (if (pair? lst) 
      (cons (add1 (car lst)) (list-add1 (cdr lst)))
      'UNDEFINED-IMPLEMENTATION-SPECIFIED-VALUE))
```

And that when used you will change a proper list into a dotted list:

```
(list-add1 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (2 3 4 . UNDEFINED-IMPLEMENTATION-SPECIFIED-VALUE)
```

The fix is to fox the procedure that makes the dotted list to handle both branches of `if`. eg.

```
(define (list-add1 lst)
  (if (pair? lst) 
      (cons (add1 (car lst)) (list-add1 (cdr lst)))
      '()))

(list-add1 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (2 3 4)
```

Of course if thats not the case, you can transform a dotted to proper by either keeping the final value in its own cons or dropping it:

```
(define (dotted->proper lst keep-value)
  (cond ((pair? lst) (cons (car lst) (dotted->proper (cdr lst) keep-value)))
        ((null? lst) '())
        (keep-value (cons lst '()))
        (else '())))

(dotted->proper '(1 2 . 3) #f) ; ==> (1 2)
(dotted->proper '(1 2 . 3) #t) ; ==> (1 2 3)
```

Comment: Good catch re improper list!

Comment: I have the procedure that produces the list with me. I could edit the question to show you the procedure. I checked whether the procedure handled both branches of `if` and it did. So I still don't know where the `unspecified` value is creeping in. Should I edit the question?

Comment: Solved it. The top most if branch was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In Guile, you can use `unspecified?` to test for an unspecified value. So, you can write a filter function, say `null-or-unspecified?`, as follows:

```
(define (null-or-unspecified? x)
  (or (null? x) (unspecified? x)))
```

Comment: I used this function like this:
`(filter null-or-unspecified? test)`  
`test` is the name of my list. It gives me an error saying `wrong type argument in position 2(() "MC-" .#<unspecified>)`

Comment: I think this list itself is giving an error to the filter function. Because even the simple filter `(= x 1)` is giving me an error. What is causing the problem?

Comment: See Sylwester's answer. It is totally spot on and you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between returning no values and returning an unspecified value. You can use `values` to return no values:

```
> (values)
>
```

If the RnRS standard says that a return value is unspecified it means that different implementations are free to return whatever value they like. Pratically it means "don't use the value returned. The implementation, you use, have chosen to make a concrete value named the unspecified value. It is printed `#<unspecified>`. Rather than removing the unspecified value from the list, I recommend you figure out where the value come from in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Guile and Chicken have special predicate `unspecified?` for it. You can filter your list like that:

```
(filter (compose not unspecified?) lst)
```

Racket has `void` function and `void?` predicate.

Also you can define `unspecified?` by yourself:

```
(define unspecified (begin))
(define (unspecified? v)
    (eq? unspecified v)
)
```