# Is there anyway to check if a function return nothing in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, guile

Is there anyway to check if a function return nothing in Scheme?

For example:

```
(define (f1)
  (if #f #f)
)
```

or

```
(define (f2) (values) )
```

or

```
(define (f3) (define var 10))
```

How can I check if `f` return nothing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28910911/124319

Comment: @coredump- thank you for providing link. I did see that thread before, but it seem to only work with my case only when the function returns `#<unspecified>`. I've added `f3`'s definition, it returns nothing instead of `#<unspecified>`

Comment: The F3 case is undefined behavior because `define` cannot be used as an expression: it can only appear at top-level body (for details, see http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.2). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18802081/124319) is relevant, as well as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504117/type-of-define-expression-in-scheme/15504315#15504315) (they are about racket, but they are valid for guile too)

Comment: @coredump- thank you. They are exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can wrap the call in something that makes a list of the values. eg.

```
(define-syntax values->list 
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expression) 
     (call-with-values (lambda () expression) 
                       (lambda g (apply list g))))))

(apply + 5 4 (values->list (values))) ; ==> 9
(null? (values->list (values)))       ; ==> #t
```

Your procedure `f2` does return exactly one value and it's undefined in the report (Scheme standard). That means it can change from call to call and the result of `(eq? (display "test1") (display "test2"))` is unknown.

Implementations usually choose a singleton value to represent the undefined value, but you can not depend on it. Implementations are free to do anything. eg. I know that in at least one Scheme implementations this happens:

```
(define test 10)
(+ (display 5) (set! test 15))
; ==> 20 (side effects prints 5, and test bound to 15)
```

It would be crazy to actually use this, but it's probably useful in the REPL.

Comment: thank you for the answer.

I did check and your function worked with `(values->list (values))`, `(values->list (if #f #f)` and `(values->list (display "smt"))`. But it did not work with `(values->list (define var 10))`.

I am using `guile` version `2.0.11`

Comment: thank to your answer, and I know that `(if #f #f)` actually return a `#<unspecified>`, not nothing. So that I edited my answer to add `f3`, it returns result of a `define` statement.

Comment: @user3909241 As I wrote in my answer only `(values)` return no answer and all procedures that return undefined values does indeed return a value and you cannot portably know what value it would be.  `(if #f #f)` can return `#t` in some strange implementation and still be according to the standard since the spec leaves it to the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In GNU Guile the function for checking this is `unspecified?`:

```
(unspecified? (if #f #f)); returns #t
(unspecified? '()); returns #f
```